# Make url with custom scheme clickable in textview

Tags: android

I have urls with custom schemes that are displayed in a `TextView`. The problem is that when I try using something like `Linkify` not the whole text section is clickable. I am following this [link](https://github.com/tir38/android-linkify-custom-scheme-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/linkifytest/MainActivity.java) to try to get it working but the link is only on `google.com`

Code copied from link but I am using Kotlin:

```
    val fullString = "This sentence contains a custom://www.google.com custom scheme url"

    mTextView.text = fullString

    val urlDetect = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+):\\/\\/([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)") // this is a terrible regex, don't use it. There are better url regexs.
    val matcher = urlDetect.matcher(fullString)
    var scheme: String? = null

    while (matcher.find()) {
        val customSchemedUrl = matcher.group(0)
        val uri = Uri.parse(customSchemedUrl)
        // Now you could create an intent yourself...
        // ...or if you want to rely on Linkify keep going
        scheme = uri.getScheme()
        break
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(scheme)) {
        Linkify.addLinks(mTextView, urlDetect, scheme)
    }
```

the output is: (custom://www.google.com) where only google.com is a link.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a clickable span would be of help here?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html